# How to add RapidXml to a CMake Project?

Tags: c++, cmake, rapidxml

I want to add RapidXML to my CMake Project, so i can use it.
My Project Structure looks like this:

```
Root
|
|_inc (for my own Headers)
|    |_main.h
|    |_CMakeList.txt
|_src (for my own Sources)
|    |_main.cpp
|    |_CMakeList.txt
|_libs (for third party libs)
|     |_rapidxml
|     |_CMakeList.txt
|_CMakeList.txt
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Solution myself. :)
In the /Root/libs/CMakeList.txt I added the following lines:

```
add_subdirectory(rapidxml)
add_library(rapidxml INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(rapidxml INTERFACE rapidxml/ )
```

if there is a better solution I am happy to hear!

Answer (score 1):

RapidXML is actually a header-only library, so you don't *need* to add it to CMake - just `#include <rapidxml/rapidxml.hpp>`. However, you can do it "properly" and in a portable way using CMake's `find_package()` function. It's not easier though!

Firstly, create a `cmake` folder in your project directory somewhere - this can be used for other libraries that don't have built-in CMake modules, too. Add it to your module path by putting this line somewhere near the top of your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

Within that folder, create a file called `FindRapidXML.cmake` and give it the following contents:

```
#
# Search and find the RapidXML library
#

# Search for the include path
find_path(
  RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES
    rapidxml.hpp
    rapidxml_utils.hpp
    rapidxml_iterators.hpp
    rapidxml_print.hpp
  HINTS "${RapidXML_ROOT_DIR}"
  PATH_SUFFIXES include rapidxml
)

# If we find the library, add it as a target
if (RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(RapidXML_FOUND TRUE)

  # Pull the version number out of the header
  message(DEBUG "Pulling version from ${RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR}/rapidxml.hpp")
  file(STRINGS "${RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR}/rapidxml.hpp"
    RapidXML_VERSION REGEX "^//[ ]*Version[ ]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[ ]*$")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^//[ ]*Version[ ]+([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)[ ]*$" "\\1\.\\2" RapidXML_VERSION "${RapidXML_VERSION}")
  
  # Print a message that we found it
  if (NOT RapidXML_FIND_QUIETLY)
    message(STATUS "Found RapidXML (found version \"${RapidXML_VERSION}\")")
  endif (NOT RapidXML_FIND_QUIETLY)

  # Create a target for it, if there isn't one already created
  if (NOT TARGET RapidXML::RapidXML)
    add_library(RapidXML::RapidXML INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(RapidXML::RapidXML PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
  endif (NOT TARGET RapidXML::RapidXML)
else ()
  # If we don't find the library, fail as appropriate
  if (RapidXML_FIND_REQUIRED)  
    message(FATAL_ERROR "RapidXML was NOT found")
  elseif (NOT RapidXML_FIND_QUIETLY)
    message(STATUS "RapidXML was NOT found")
  endif (RapidXML_FIND_REQUIRED)
endif (RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR)

# Hide the variables that we set
mark_as_advanced(RapidXML_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Then, you can import RapidXML into your project with one simple line:

```
find_package(RapidXML REQUIRED)
```

And you can include it in a target like so:

```
target_link_libraries(<target> PRIVATE RapidXML::RapidXML)
```

The beauty of this is that you can use the options from [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) to have it required or not, so you get an earlier failure if it's not found. The `FindRapidXML.cmake` file is also reusable in other projects, the loic to find it is kept out of your main cmake file, and if it's installed into non-standard locations you can hint to where it is using `HINTS <path>` as you would with any other package.